# Moving databases between servers - using network mapping

Tags: sql-server, backup

I manage a set of database servers on virtual machines. We are in the process of migrating all of our databases from Windows server 2017 VMs to Windows 2022 Server VMs.

I use MS SMSS to manage my databases.

I am looking for a script that will allow me to migrate all the databases in one shot from the old server to the new one. I understand that I should need the log files as well as the .bak files. Please note that I want to use a mapped drive to drop the log and data files into due to space restrictions. Currently I am using this code as a back up code.

```
DECLARE @backupPath NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @backupPath = '\\YourNetworkDrive\BackupFolder\' -- Specify your network drive path

DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE' AND name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @backupFile NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @backupFile = @backupPath + @db_name + '.bak'

    BACKUP DATABASE @db_name TO DISK = @backupFile

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Oddly enough it copies SOME (about 10%) of the databases but not the full list. But gives no errors.
I am also looking for the code to restore on the new server, as the one I am currently using shows "completed successfully" but doesnt do anything.

Help appreciated!!!

Copy code

```
DECLARE @backupPath NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @backupPath = '\\YourNetworkDrive\BackupFolder\' -- Specify your network drive path

DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE' AND name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @backupFile NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @backupFile = @backupPath + @db_name + '.bak'

    BACKUP DATABASE @db_name TO DISK = @backupFile

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Restore code

```
DECLARE @backupPath NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @backupPath = 'D:\YourBackupFolder\' -- Specify the path where the backup files are located on the new server

DECLARE @db_name NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE' AND name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @restoreFile NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @restoreFile = @backupPath + @db_name + '.bak'

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.master_files WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = @db_name)
    BEGIN
        -- Restore database
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @sql = 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + @db_name + '] FROM DISK = N''' + @restoreFile + ''' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY'
        EXEC(@sql)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Backup file not found for database: ' + @db_name
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: That code smells like it came from CrapGPT...

Comment: Have you considered using availability groups to do this?

Comment: Which side is failing, the backup or the restore? Can you try using a `STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY` cursor? On a side note: the `RESTORE` statement can be fully parameterized same as the `BACKUP`, you don't need dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Charlieface It's interesting because the back up code only backs up like 10% of the dbs. and the restore won't restore any of them.

Comment: @PatrickHurst trust be told im not familiar with that, ill have to look into that.

Comment: OK try `DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE' AND name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')` do note that if the databases don't exist at all on the new server then your current script will not restore them.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16
You may find setting up a temporary availability group solves your problem. When you have failed over to the new site and confirmed all is well you can prune the old nodes out.

Comment: For debugging, instead of running the commands in the cursor loop, print the SQL statements and copy and paste it into a new query editor window.